# how do I rewrite an url but include some of the same url content

Tags: apache

I have incoming requests going to video.mydomain.com/myvideo.avi that need to be re-written to www.mydomain.com/myvideo.avi. This is in apache 2 on RHEL 6.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite.  If it's not already then you may have to install it in Apache.  Add something like this to your VirtualHost conf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} video\.([^\.]+\.[^\.]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The regular expression in the RewriteCond line will match a pattern like video.mydomain.com but the parentheses around the [^.]+.[^.]+ part define it to be a capture group.  The value of that is then found in %1 (since it's the first capture group you defined) and you can put that into the new URL in the RewriteRule part with the %1.   Note that the example above will work with any domain name that starts with video.

Comment: Scope changed a bit :( Response I got was: The rewriting does not seem to work yet.
E.g. the url http://video.example.com.org/video/videoname should become http://www.example.com/video/videoname

Comment: No problem - just omit the "www." from the RewriteRule above: RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI}  
I hope that helps!